# How to validate selection in Laravel Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am building an app to create Football (Soccer) matches. When I create a match, I need to check that the selected teams are in the chosen league.

When the form is submitted I would like to display a message that the wrong league selected if so.

There is `store()` method in controller

```php
$match = new Match;
$match->round = $request->round;
$match->league_id = $request->league;
$match->home_team_id = $request->home_team;
$match->away_team_id = $request->away_team;
$match->match_date = $request->match_date;
$match->location = $request->location;
```

Team model:

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    public function league() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }
}
```

League model:

```php
class League extends Model
{
    public function teams() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Team');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know which league each team is in? If you have models and relationships defined for that, it would help if you share them in the question.

Comment: i have added code from team and league models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the incoming request using a closure rule to make a database query to return `true` if does not exist the League which `id` is the given `league_id` and have the teams with the given `home_team_id` and the `away_team_id`. Then if the League doesn't exists, throw a validation fail:

```php
$request->validate([
    'home_team_id' => ['required'],
    'away_team_id' => ['required'],
    'league_id' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $condition = League::where('id', request('league_id')
                ->whereHas('teams', function($q) {
                    $q->where('id', request('home_team_id'))->where('id', request('away_team_id'));
                })->doesntExist();
            if ($condition) {
                $fail('Both Teams must belong to the selected League.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

References:

- Validation [Using Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures).
- Eloquent [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).
- DB Query Builder [Determining If Records Exist](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist).

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) on Validation